# Enum explicit cast to int returns 1 (and warning)

Tags: php, enums, php-8.1

Here's a runnable example: https://onlinephp.io/c/d9c58

```
enum DigitEnum : int
{
    case TWO = 2;
}

$i = (int) DigitEnum::TWO; // emits a warning, expected

echo $i; // outputs 1
```

The output is:

```
Warning: Object of class DigitEnum could not be converted to int in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line 9
1
```

I understand the warning - I'm expecting that - but I don't understand the reasoning behind `$i` getting a value of `1`. I mean as opposed to `0` or `null` or `[NaN]`.

Reading https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting, there seems to be a precedent for "failed" conversions to result in `0`, so that's probably what I'd expect?

I cannot find anything in the [Enum documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.php) to explain why this might be a special case and is entirely legitimate. That's not to say it's not there somewhere, I just couldn't find it ;-)

Comment: I have a feeling it has something to do with converting to boolean first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are simply singleton objects. If you explicitly convert other class instances to int you also get 1 along with a warning.

You should use `DigitEnum::TWO->value` for the backed value.

According to: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

`intval()` should not be used on objects, as doing so will emit an E_NOTICE level error and return 1.

Comment: It's fine, the rest is in the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting.from-other: "Caution
The behaviour of converting to int is undefined for other types. Do not rely on any observed behaviour, as it can change without notice."

Comment: Haha, *of course* [slaps head, goes a bit red]. Thanks @Siu! Makes perfect sense. I even read the bit of the docs I include in my previous comment here, and didn't pay attn to it. Thanks again :-)